# Custom imageview not added in linear layout runtime

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

My need is to add circle imageview in linear layout runtime.

I tried code mentioned below, but it not give me a solution, but if i try the default image view it works fine, but creating problem in custom imageview(com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView).

can any one suggest or help me to come out from this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al_friends.size(); i++) 
{

    ImageView  iv_friend_profile = new com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView(ProfileActivity.this);

    iv_friend_profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    iv_friend_profile.setTag(i);
    iv_friend_profile.setOnClickListener(new FriendProfileClicker());
    ll_friends.addView(iv_friend_profile);

}
```

Comment: what do you get? and paste com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView code probably error is there

Comment: @Xenione com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView is a class of library poject, out put of above code is, it shows blank layout.